# How to open iPhone address book using Contacts.framework

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, contacts, addressbook

I'm trying to open Address book using new Contacts.framework. This framework is introduced in iOS 9.0, I've tried some ways to open the view controller but ends up crashing. Has anyone faced similar issue?

```
NSError *error;

CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
NSArray *cArray = [store unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:[CNContact predicateForContactsMatchingName:@"Kate"] keysToFetch:@[CNContactEmailAddressesKey,CNContactPhoneNumbersKey] error:&error];

CNContactViewController *cVC = [CNContactViewController viewControllerForContact:[cArray objectAtIndex:0]];
[self presentViewController:cVC animated:YES completion:^{

}];
```

Comment: No. Contacts framework is easy and works fine.

Comment: Yes, but I've landed into crash by launching the address book using contacts.framework

Comment: But you don't show any code or even say what means, so who knows what you are doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Contacts.framework is only available in iOS 9.0 onwards. Here is the code which checks for the availability and because launching contact picker view controller.

Code to invoke contact picker view controller

```
if ([CNContactPickerViewController class]) {
     CNContactPickerViewController *cVC = [[CNContactPickerViewController alloc] init];
     [self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:cVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.x**

```
let contactPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
contactPicker.delegate = self
self.present(contactPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```